# Why aren't gravitons spin 1?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-spin, gauge-theory, gravitational-waves, yang-mills

Expressing the metric as $g_{\mu \nu} = \eta_{\mu \nu} + h_{\mu \nu}$, assuming $h_{\mu \nu} \ll 1$ we can write the Einstein Hilbert action to leading order in $h_{\mu \nu}$ and quantize the linearized Einstein Hilbert action to construct the graviton field. Gravitons are spin 2 particles, which is easiest to see by noting that $h_{\mu \nu}$ has two indices. These enjoy a "gauge symmetry" corresponding to diffeomorphisms.

However, classically, gravity can be understood to be largely analogous to a gauge theory. The Christoffel symbol $\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\beta \mu}$ takes the place of $A^a_\mu T^a$ as the gauge field.

Note that $\Gamma^{\alpha}_{\beta \mu}$ has three indices, however the $\alpha,\beta$ indices can be understood as a matrix, much like the Lie algebra elements $T^a$ in Yang Mills theory.

If we quantize this field instead shouldn't we not be able to realize gravity as a theory mediated by spin 1 gauge particles?

(This should be especially true if we take the action to be the Kretschmann scalar, which seems to be equivalent to the Yang Mills Lagrangian.

$$
\mathrm{Tr}(F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}) \leftrightarrow R^a_{b \mu \nu} {R^b_{a}}^{\mu \nu}
$$

However, this would obviously give a different theory than Einstein gravity.)

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/108523/the-spin-connection).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/108230/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/263572/2451 and links therein.

Comment: see  my answer here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/11542/  .charges play a role in attraction and repulsion together with the spin.

Comment: It sure feels like 3 questions: a) Physically, coupling to the energy-momentum tensor dictates spin 2.  b) Formally, the weak field expansion of Einstein's equations produce a metric perturbation field which is spin 2. c) Indeed, the intuitive gauge-theory simulacrum for gravity is the gauged tangent space Lorentz group, effected by the spin connection ω, related to Γ, which is not a tensor, and which is utilized in supergravity; however, possibly counterintuitively, it  demonstrably leads to spin 2. You apparently want to focus on 3)?

Comment: Yes, question 3 was more my question. I was not aware that it somehow also leads to the spin 2 description

Comment: It's technical in the translation. Best outlined in a good supergravity book. At the end of the day, the Vierbeine involved gang up into metrics and their immanent graviton excitation fields...

Comment: ...perhaps (3.3) [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.03884) might help--unless it doesn't.

Comment: See also [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/665273) & [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/329678).

Answer (score 2):

Imagine a gravitational wave traveling along the $z$ axis. We can choose coordinates (aka fix a gauge if you prefer that language) where the components of the metric perturbation are
\begin{equation}
h_{\mu\nu} = \left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & h_+ & h_\times & 0 \\
0 & - h_\times & h_+ & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\end{equation}
where $h_+$ and $h_\times$ are the amplitudes of the $+$ and $\times$ polarizations.

Under a rotation about the $z$ axis by an angle $\psi$, the time parts of the above metric perturbation $h_{00}$ and $h_{0i}$ are invariant, while the spatial part $h_{ij}$ transforms as
\begin{equation}
h_{ij} \rightarrow R(\psi)_{ia} h_{ab} R_{jb}(\psi)
\end{equation}
where $R(\psi)_{ij}$ is a rotation matrix
\begin{equation}
R(\psi)_{ij} = \left(
\begin{matrix}
\cos\psi & \sin \psi & 0 \\
-\sin\psi & \cos\psi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\right)
\end{equation}
Working through the algebra and using various trig identities, you can show this implies that $h_{ij}$ is invariant under a rotation by $\pi$, which is characteristic of a spin-2 particle. In general after a rotation you will find that the components of $h_{ij}$ are multiplied by functions of $2\psi$, another characteristic sign of a spin-2 particle.

The precise definition is in terms of [helicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicity_(particle_physics)). An eigenstate of the helicity operator corresponds to a circularly polarized gravitational wave. A *circularly polarized* wave with $h = h_+=e^{\pm i\pi/2}h_\times$ will transform as $h \rightarrow e^{\pm i 2\psi} h$. The $\pm 2$ here are the eigenvalues of the helicity operator; a massless particle with a $\pm 2$ helicity eigenstates *is* a massless spin-2 particle.