# Gravity = Yang-Mills squared? What is the Lagrangian?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, lagrangian-formalism, supersymmetry, yang-mills

In the following comment and references, it is mentioned that gravity can be understood as yang mills squared. What is the Lagrangian of a Yang Mills squared theory? Can anyone provide a quick primer?

---

In this comment:

[Why are string theorist so indifferent to the gauge structure of gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/247193/)

Then in these references:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.08267

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTUQw2wxck8

Comment: See also [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/329678).

Answer (score 2):

1. The statement
   $$ \text{(super) gravity} = [\text{(super) Yang-Mills]}^2 $$
   is the punch line of the [Bern-Carrasco-Johansson](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.0476) (BCJ) colour-kinematic duality conjecture that the perturbative *on-shell scattering amplitudes* for (super) gravity are the [double-copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_copy_theory) of gluon scattering amplitudes in (super) Yang-Mills theory.
2. Refs. 1-2 are some recent work on implementing manifest BCJ colour-kinematic duality at the level of the *off-shell action/Lagrangian,* cf. OP's title question.

References:

1. L. Borsten, B. Jurco, H. Kim, T. Macrelli, C. Saemann & M. Wolf, *BRST-Lagrangian Double Copy of Yang-Mills Theory,* [arXiv:2007.13803](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.13803).
2. L. Borsten, B. Jurco, H. Kim, T. Macrelli, C. Saemann & M. Wolf, *Double Copy from Homotopy Algebras,* [arXiv:2102.11390](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.11390).

Comment: Thank you. In the following reference http://ift.uni.wroc.pl/~mborn35/files/proc/Krasnov.pdf page 23. The author mentions this Lagrangian as a "double yang-mills" version of gravity: $ S=\int (\operatorname{Tr} \sqrt{F \wedge F})^2$, but does not provide a reference. Can you shed more light on this Lagrangian or know of a link where I can read more about it?

Comment: FWIW, Krasnov's talk seems based on his work: https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.08640 , https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.7159 , and a [Plebanski-like action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plebanski_action).

Comment: Is the Lagrangian of a double copy Yang mills $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_{\text{copy 1}} + \mathcal{L}_{\text{copy 2}}$ or $\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_{\text{copy 1}} \mathcal{L}_{\text{copy 2}}$?